# Threading in a irc Chat bot

Tags: python, multithreading, chat, bots

Writing a chat bot that i think needs more then 1 thread. First Main thread reads constantly the chat. From time to time I need to check the moderators which i need to get from an URL((JSON)) and provide to the main thread so he can for example ban someone but not an moderator.

First Question: How do i make a thread run every 30 secs. I dont want to pause it. I want to run it, finish after getting the moderators list and then after some time run it again.

Code of Main File:

```
#Requests module, which gets JSON data from an url
#To get moderators in the chat.
def secondThread():
    while(True):
        getModsList()


def chatReading():
    #Creates socket to the twitch irc chat
    s = openSocket()
   #Joins a specific chat room
    joinRoom(s)

    while(True):
        #Revieves messages from irc                  
        derp = s.recv(8192)
        derp=derp.decode('utf-8')
        temp = str.split(derp, "\n")
        readbuffer = temp.pop()

        #Loop which prints scanned thing from twitch irc chat
        for line in temp:
            #Time stamp    
            print(time.strftime('%X'), end=" : ")
            #Pings server back    
            pingPong(s, line)

            #This just displays the message recieved more readable User:Message
            try:
                print(getUser(line) + " typed :" + getMessage(line))
            except (IndexError, UnicodeEncodeError):
                print("Not an user")


def main():

    thread_1 = threading.Thread(target=chatReading, args=[])
    thread_2 = threading.Thread(target=secondThread, args=[])
    thread_1.start()
    thread_2.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Second file with getModList

```
moderators = None

def getModsList():

    gotList = False

    while(gotList != True):
        jsonList = requests.get(CHANNEL_GROUP)
        #If the jsonList status_code == 200 that means that it got the list,
        #every other number is bad.
        statusFlag=jsonList.status_code

        if(statusFlag == 200):
            gotList = True
        else:
            print("Failed to get mods list, trying again")
            continue

        jsonList=jsonList.json()

        #this gets the mods list
        moderators = jsonList['chatters']['moderators']
        time.sleep(10)
```

Second question would be more an advice. How do i plan the project? Its my first more serious project and I'm having trouble see how to plan it. I want to add later more funcionality to the bot like commands for user, mods, a raffle where a user by command can join only once, and after 5 minutes a winner is chosen. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For your first question, you can use [`sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.sleep). 

For your second question, I would suggest creating a Bot class.

Comment: I know i can use sleep() but i would like to learn how to make it like i described. Just for learning purposes.

Comment: What do you mean by "finish after getting the mods"?

Comment: Getting the moderators list from the url.

Comment: You can't call a thread's `start()` method more than once. You can just start another thread, instead.

Comment: Well, but i can start it, end it and again start etc.. In a loop with a condition based on a timer. I just dont know how to end a thread.

Comment: Just call `return` at the end of the thread